# Get JSON String from API java

Tags: java, json, api, okhttp

How can I get String Json by Response from API in Java?
I am trying to get And Parse them to Object but I not work

```
public class tedst {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Request res = new Request.Builder().url("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Hanoi&APPID=bffca17bcb552b8c8e4f3b82f64cccd2&units=metric").build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(res).execute();
           Data data = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Data.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, can you accept the answer I gave to help others?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Response` object should have a `body()` method that lets you retrieve what has been responded to your call.

Your code should look like this:

```java
try (Response response = client.newCall(res).execute();
     ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
    Data data = gson.fromJson(body.string(), Data.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You are my Angel. Thanks so much <3